# What is the better way of show a Modal Form with a dim background?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

As you can see on the image above a modal form with dim background and this how I do it.
I have two Forms and I'm opening them simultaneously.

```
private DimBackground dim;
private Modal modal;

private void ListEmployee_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var row = employee.ListEmployee.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Employee emp = new Employee().Get(row.Cells["Employee_ID"].Value.ToString());
        dim = new DimBackground();
        dim.Show();
        modal = new Modal(emp,dim);
        modal.ShowDialog();
    }     
}
```

For me this is not a good approach for this. There's a problem in doing it

- When closing these two form simultaneously, it lose the focus on mainform

> To fix that, I close the modal form and hide the dim form

- Alt F4 closing, you need to use these two times to close two forms

> When i tried to disable the form closing, The form got freeze

How can i achieve this in a better/cleaner way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible modifications to apply to your dimmed Overlay and Modal Forms:

1. Modify the contructor of the Overlay so you can pass an instance of the Modal dialog.
2. Make the caller Form the Overlay Owner (with `[DimBackground].Show(this);`), so the Overlay can use the Owner object to adapt to its dimensions.
3. The Overlay subscribes to the `FormClosed` event of instance of the Modal Form it received.
4. Modify the constructor of the Modal Form so it can accept the class object used to show the informations.
5. When the Modal Form closes, if raises its `FormClosed` event, the Overlay then closes itself and activates the caller Form.

Add the required `null` checks.

---

```
//Caller Form
private void ListEmployee_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //(...)
    var row = employee.ListEmployee.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Employee emp = new Employee().Get(row.Cells["Employee_ID"].Value.ToString());
    DimBackground overlay = new DimBackground(new Modal(emp));
    overlay.Show(employee);
}


public partial class DimBackground : Form
{
    Form frmDialog = null; 
    public DimBackground(Form dialog)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frmDialog = dialog;
        this.frmDialog.FormClosed += (obj, evt) => { this.Close(); };
    }

    private void DimBackground_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.frmDialog.ShowDialog();

    private void DimBackground_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner == null) return;
        this.Bounds = this.Owner.Bounds;
    }

    private void DimBackground_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Owner?.Activate();
    }
}

public partial class Modal : Form
{
    public Modal() : this(null) { }
    public Modal(Employee employee)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Do something with the employee object
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem, How i'm gonna close these?

Comment: When you close the modal dialog, everything closes. Except the caller Form, of course. That one is Activated.

Comment: And, please, don't modify the code in your question with what I posted here, nobody understands anymore what's what. Also, you forgot `overlay.Show(this);`. Without `this`, the instance of the current Form, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Btw,  overlay.Show(this), i cannot use this keyword to these. The modal close successfully. but it lose the focus on the form

Comment: You need to modify your Forms as shown here. If you don't, again, nothing works.

Comment: I use class, to that cell click event that's why i can't use this keyword

Comment: You don't have access to an instance of the Form where these controls (`ListEmployee` and Co.) are shown?

Comment: Anyway, i tried it to my form but still it lose focus, i will update my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188854/discussion-between-diether-and-jimi).